# Is it possible to remove movie frames that contain no audio?

Tags: audio, video-editing

I have an AVI file that contains a lot of empty frames, i.e. frames without audio or even picture changes. Is it possible to remove those frames?

Specifically, I have an 8 GB AVI file where almost 20-30% of the frames are empty. Their length and positions in the file are random (some can be short, only 1 second, while others can be 10 minutes long).

I would appreciate any advice on how to remove these frames. Or are there tools or other video formats like MP4 which are more suitable?

Comment: @random, Hi, I do not know why this question is consider off topic. It is about asking for a software that can help to perform such operation. and according to faq, it mention about `computer software`. Please enlighten me. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, product recommendations are off topic

Comment: Technically he isn't asking for a recommendation, he just wants to know if such software exists. Seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: @skypecakes Thanks for the support. My English is just so bad that sometime people mis-understand what I really mean. (I think maybe there is no such software since it is quite quiet in Superuser)

Comment: For future reference, please follow [these guidelines](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software/5373#5373) on asking questions that may require software recommendations.

Comment: Would the movie still work afterwards or does the format require X frames per second? Even if those are empty frames?

Comment: @KronoS, I wish to use the guidelines that you mention but I could not find any such software. Some more, the guidelines does not include such situations. I have added two question templates inside the guidelines for your consideration. I would also like to take this opportunity to thank nixda and Indrek for helping re-phrase my question.

Answer (score 0):

I actually once built a tool that does exactly that (except for the sound factor).
I don't have the tool anymore but I will describe how it works (and maybe build it again soon)

Using [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) you break down the film to frames, one per second, then use [compare](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php) to delete all the duplicate (>90% similarity) images.

Aftet that, you'll end up with different sequences of numbered image files (1..20,30..45,etc.), so you take that up, and again use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) to keep only the portions of the file that has mostly different frames.

I know this is a descriptive answer rather than a practical one, but I'll work on that tool and update here when possible.

Comment: This is a theoretical approach and a good one. I look forward to your tool & guide.